# Python BeautifulSoup4 get_text() or regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 2.7.5 and BeautifulSoup4.
I need to cut text from html tags.
I have output `<a class="username offline popupctrl" href="member.php?20938-NarutoO" title="NarutoO je offline"><strong><font color="#5566CC">NarutoO</font></strong></a>` after a command:

```
  print post_owner[0]
```

I need only nickname: `NarutoO`
and don't want to use `get_text()`.

My code:

```
post_owner = soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'username offline popupctrl'})
for row1 in post_owner:
    text = ''.join(row1.findAll(text=True))
    data1 = text.strip()
    text_file.write("USER NAME\n")
    member_count = member_count + 1
    data1 = data1.encode('utf-8')
    text_file.write(str(data1) + '\n')
```

I use some solution in other posts.If I understood it correctly, `findAll` gives me a list of all matches. My code will print all matches in a row. I just need access elements in `post_owner` list and use them without html tags. Some example like:

```
  print post_owner[0]
  print post_owner[4]
  print post_owner[2]
  .
  .
  .
```

sorry for bad explanation, I am really tired :o

Comment: Why don't you want to use `get_text` when it's clearly the best option?

Comment: Because when I use get_text with findAll it returns error code.

Comment: what is the error message specifically?

Comment: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `soup.select` and `get()`

`[i.get('title') for i in soup.select('.username')]`